# Only Chrome corrupts my web site format

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My enthusiast site can be found at http://www.488.cyberpictures.net - it was simply put together with Notepad and an HTML programmer's Reference for version 4. I am no expert on the finer points of web design and any routines used have been found by Google searches. So when I hit a problem I have to ask community experts.

I check the output using IE and Firefox and validate the coding and everything looked fine to me until I brought up my web site with the Chrome browser - the formatting was a complete shambles with the overall width of the table much larger than it should be. I've tried to crack the problem myself but I only seem to make matters worse when returning to use IE or Firefox.

If anyone could give me guidance to achieve cross platform compatibility, this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Initial Chrome display issue

I looked at the source code on your page...  using `align=center` is not generally compatible with newer pages (for example, HTML5 pages) and shouldn't be used.

The easy fix to your issue...

In the main DIV, replace this:

`<div align="center">`

With this:

`<div style="max-width:800px; margin:auto">`

Adjust the width here to the width you actually want the content to be.   When I was playing around in the Chrome inspector, this quick fix resolves the issue on your page.

### Internet Explorer 8 display issue

I believe the issue you are running in to is very specific to IE in how it handles tables.   Looking at your source code, I see you are using three columns, but because of the colSpan, never really have more than two on any one line.

IE 8 (and also 9 I believe) has issues with table column widths when all three columns are never defined.   This is causing the layout to break.   The fix is somewhat of a hack, but it looks like this:

```
<div style="max-width:860px; margin:auto">

<table class="dxb2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="200"></td>
        <td width="451"></td>
        <td width="205"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="651" colspan="2" valign="top">
```

If you look at the code above, what I've done is inserted an extra row at the top of your table.   This row is essentially blank, and it's only purpose is to define all three columns and give them their default widths.   This fixes the IE issue with calculating these.

I made a copy of your source code on my desktop and edited as above... seems to work great in correcting the IE issue (I have a VM here where I can test on IE8).   But let me know how it works for you...  hopefully that resolves the last of the display issues :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestion. I will certainly investigate this concept and a later date bone up on HTML5.

Comment: You're welcome...   looking at the results in the browser, I'm sure this will resolve the display issue you are having.    Give it a try and let me know how it works out.

Comment: Well it certainly seemed to do the business with Chrome 33 now rendering as expected. The only issue is that change seems to have passed the batten on IE8 which of course is the buffer stop for Xp. No problems with IE11 though, A third of my site visitors this month, just under 2000 of them, are using that browser version. Whether the numbers will start to fall off with Xp going off the radar with MS is a bit of unknown.  Can you see a fix to that problem by any chance?

Comment: Have a solution for you...  will update answer in just a minute here.

Comment: Second part of the solution for IE8 added to the answer.   Let me know if that resolves the issue for you :)

Comment: I was thinking along those lines myself but often a solution for one browser breaks another but hey this problem has affected around 200 visitors this month so its got to be worth a try. I was wondering if there was any merit in adding height="1" and possibly no break space for each td in the first row?

Comment: @user3448090 I'm not *personally* aware of any benefit of the extra items...  from what I've read it seems that IE simply needs a "starting point" to work out the column widths.  However, I don't think it would hurt either...  I had considered using a no break space myself, but decided against it once the solution worked without it.